# Select Between dates and count variables

Tags: sql, date, select, count

I have made a stored procedure and i need it to check through each date within a date range. the dates are passed from the browser (My form) and then set as a variable in the stored procedure.

when it is checking between the date range i also need it to count other things for example i have a @max_users constant that is 20 if the dates between there selected date has 20 people within it set a variable to false.

this is the code a have tried so far to select between a date range.

```
    SELECT (SOME FORM OF COUNTER TO COUNT VARIABLES WOUDL GO HERE)
    FROM table 
    WHERE @Startdate => @StartDate AND =< @EndDate
```

I am new to SQL and having trouble with this.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE spBusinessRules (@Startdate date, @Enddate date, @EmployeeID int)

/*****
Name:spBusinessRules
Description: Checks the holiday agaisnt all the business rules ready for accepting or declining
*****/
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Holidays
        WHERE @Startdate >= @Startdate AND @Enddate <= @Enddate AND (SELECT jobrole FROM Employees WHERE ID = @EmployeeID) = JobRole
    END

    SELECT * FROM Employees
```

Above is my latest attemp which i am still getting problems from

Comment: You're basically thinking of looping, and that's *not* the general way that SQL works (well). In SQL, we try to write a query that deals with the entire set of data. Unfortunately, you've been too vague in your question for me to suggest an actual query. If you could add some sample data, and then for certain values of `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`, the expected results, we can try to write a query that computes the entire result - not by going through each date in turn.

Comment: Well, `WHERE @Startdate >= @Startdate AND @Enddate <= @Enddate` are two comparisons that are trivially true. You probably wanted to be comparing columns from the table (without the `@`) to the parameter values. Also, if you're trying to find rows from the `holidays` table which *overlap* in any way the range defined by `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`, you're missing a lot of edge cases. The best way to find overlapping rows is `StartDate < @EndDate and @StartDate < EndDate`. Finally, if you're just looking for `0` or `more than 0`, then use `EXISTS` not `COUNT`.

Comment: i though count was more suited because i am trying to count a certain amount of values within it because if it counts more than lets say 10 it changes a BIT to false
would this still work with exists

Comment: No, I was just jumping the gun because it's a common beginner mistake to use `COUNT()` when all you actually want to know is whether any rows exist. As I say, if you can add some sample data and expected results, I may be able to help. At the moment, all we've got are your attempts, and whilst I can spot some obvious issues with them, I still don't know enough about what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically i have a system for holiday booking, this proc check the rules which when its passed them all evaluates a variable to true to book the holiday. the start date and end date are the dates to and from the suer wants off so it needs to check if 10 more people are off between them dates with a count (i think anyway) it also uses the employees id which is passed so it can find there jobrole(lets say there admin for now). and then if there is 10 admin off evaluate to false and not let them book :) i have a large list of rules but if i can understand this one i can probably complete the rest

Comment: You probably [don't want to be using BETWEEN with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (or inclusive bounds) - this applies to all RDBMSs, essentially (although you haven't listed yours).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to declare a function in TSQL that gets a parameter (Date). Then you can do your calculation in the function and return the value back to this statement to display.

Comment: Umm, he's trying to _write_ the procedure, so this essentially tells him nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i managed to do it here was the working outcome

```
DECLARE @EmployeeID int
DECLARE @StartDate date
DECLARE @EndDate date
DECLARE @JobRoleID int

SET @JobRoleID = 2
SET @EmployeeID = 2010
SET @Startdate = '2013-03-13'
SET @EndDate = '2015-03-14'

/*Sets The max days off for the users jobrole*/
DECLARE @EmployeeJobroleMAX int
SET @EmployeeJobroleMAX = (SELECT maxusersOffPerDay 
                           FROM JobRole 
                           WHERE @JobRoleID = JobRole.ID)
DECLARE @JobRoleOff int

BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateCount date
    SET @DateCount = @Startdate

    DECLARE @EndDateCheck date
    SET @EndDateCheck = DATEADD(d, 1, @EndDate)

    WHILE(@DateCount <> @EndDateCheck)
        BEGIN

            SET @JobRoleOff = (SELECT COUNT(*) JobRoleID 
                               FROM Employees 
                               RIGHT JOIN Holidays 
                                       ON Employees.ID = Holidays.EmployeeID 
                               WHERE @EmployeeID = Employees.ID 
                                     AND Holidays.StartDate >= @StartDate 
                                     AND Holidays.EndDate <= @EndDate)
            SET @DateCount = DATEADD(d, 1, @DateCount)
        END

    IF(@JobRoleOff >= 1)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @JobRoleOff AS Failed
        END
END
```

Comment: Um, if I've indented this correctly, you're not checking all days while looping.  Can somebody check my work?  Regardless, this is probably not the best option - can we get sample data and desired results, please?

Comment: you are correct. i have now realised i did not test proply and it is not the full answer :(. this jsut checks the start and end dates. it does not check between the start and end dates